# Unable to run apollo server from React project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, vite, apollo-server

I am trying to run Apollo server for Graphql to be used my React project, but it is giving me errors. I have used Typescript and followed this https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started/#complete-example
I have created the index.ts file under src folder.
It is giving the following error when trying to run with 'npm start'

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module ' ......\dist\index.ts'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "start": "npm run compile && node ./src/index.js"
  },
```

tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "outDir": "dist",    
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
```

Comment: Why are you [diverging from the tutorial you're following](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started/#set-up-with-typescript)? Your `start` script should be executing `./dist/index.js`, not `./src/index.js`.

Comment: had the same error and I changed because I don't have a dist folder. index.js is in src folder. Do I create one manually?

Comment: Look at tsconfig - outDir is "dist" - that's where it will put the transpiled file which is what will actually run. You can't run typescript code directly.

Comment: @MichelFloyd thank you. I have "start": "npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js" and still giving the same error. Please help as I am not able to fix it .